# windows installer installation progress status messages

Tags: c#, .net, windows-installer

I'm using VS 2010(C#) for my windows application and its setup package creation. Is it possible to display custom status messages like 'Currently installing database scripts...' below the progress bar by overriding any installer methods or any other way ??

Answer (score 2):

Here is codeporject's link In which CustomAction in setup project briefly described. [How to create custom dialog boxes using the Setup Project in Visual Studio 2010.](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/181395/How-to-create-custom-dialog-boxes-using-the-Web-Se)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know is it possible with VS. There is an [Action Table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa367516%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) inside Windows Installer database. You can edit it with special tool 'Orca' from Windows SDK. Or you can use Wix Toolset (`ProgressText` - element)